# How to combine .dash segments to one file and convert it to .mp4?

Tags: ubuntu, video, mp4, mpeg-dash

I have downloaded video and audio `.dash` segments.

For video:

```
10-video=2990000-0.dash
12-video=2990000-48.dash
14-video=2990000-96.dash
and so on...
```

For audio:

```
11-audio_spa=96000.dash
13-audio_spa=96000-0.dash
15-audio_spa=96000-96255.dash
and so on...
```

How can I combine these segments to one file and convert it to `.mp4`?

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

**UPDATE:** 
When trying to combine with `ffmpeg`, I get an error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55e71f863bc0] could not find corresponding track id 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55e71f863bc0] could not find corresponding trex
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55e71f863bc0] error reading header
10-video=2990000-0.dash: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I have `index.mpd` file but I don't know how to include that file when combining `.dash` files

Comment: not a full answer, but check https://superuser.com/questions/1278394/using-the-busybox-cat-command-for-mpeg-dash-segment-merge-in-windows-the-argu for a starting point

Comment: Already tried but I get an error:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55668f960a40] could not find corresponding track id 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55668f960a40] could not find corresponding trex
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55668f960a40] error reading header
combined.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input. It seems like I need some init file which I don't have :(